# How to create gaps when using group / groupX / groupY in Observable Plot?

Tags: javascript, plot, grouping, observablehq, observable-plot

On [line charts](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/plot-line#cell-760) *"if some of the x or y channel values are undefined (or null or NaN), gaps will appear between adjacent points".*

If my dataset contains such undefined values, how can I achieve that these also remain when I use `group` / `groupX` / `groupY`?

The below plot is created (some settings removed for brevity) using a dataset where all x values (`timestamp`) are set and some y values (`temp`) are `undefined`.

```
marks: [
  Plot.frame(),
  Plot.line(data, { x: "timestamp", y: "temp", stroke: "sensor_id" }),
  Plot.line(data,  Plot.groupX({ y: "mean" }, { x: d => new Date(d.timestamp.getTime()).setSeconds(0, 0), y: "temp", stroke: "black" }))
]
```

[image]

How can I achieve that this aggregates to `undefined`? Is there a setting how `group` behaves when a single value / all values are `undefined`?

I managed to make it work by providing a custom aggregation function that takes care of `undefined` values, but I think there should be an easier way to achieve this. It seems like I am missing something.

```
Plot.line(data, 
          Plot.groupX(
            // Here I check if the grouping consists of a single falsy value
            { y: data => (data.length == 1 && !data[0]) ? undefined : data.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / data.length }, 
            { x: d => new Date(d.timestamp.getTime()).setSeconds(0, 0), y: "temp", stroke: "black"
))
```

[image]

*Cross-posted to the [ObservableHQ forum](https://talk.observablehq.com/t/how-to-create-gaps-when-using-group-groupx-groupy-in-observable-plot/6202)*